# Custom shape form

Tags: html, css, forms, svg

I have a form which fit in custom shape. Question is how to expand this shape if more inputs appends. I try:

• SVG shape, but SVG can't contain HTML elements

• CSS clip-path, but... compatability http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

• Background image SVG, don't work with background-size, can't scale to one direction

• Background image PNG/JPG, bad quality with scaling

[image]

Comment: SVG can contain HTML elements, look up `<foreignObject>`

Comment: You could use pure CSS based shape. Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8kq6ksbe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad quality when scaling a raster image also depends on the original (pixel) size of that image. Given the fact that it's just a big surface with the same color, a PNG image should be quite small in file size, even on a larger scale. For instance, a shape like that on a 2000x2000 px PNG image would take less than 60KB, especially when you apply [PNGCrush](http://pngcrush.com/).

Another alternative you may look at is a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas). On a canvas you can draw shapes yourself. [Canvas support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas) is a lot better than clip-path (IE 9+).

Comment: You'll get aliasing effects on the diagonal line though.

Comment: With JPG you do due to the lossy compression. For PNG that's not the case. That's another reason to use PNG in this case (it will be smaller in file size too).